# R: ggfortify: specify column to use for labels in plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggfortify` to draw some diagnostic plots for my `lm` and `glm` objects, but I can't figure out how to specify the labels to use. Right now, it uses the observation numbers. I'd rather it use a column named "community" in `df.ca` for the label names.

The [GLM example here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggfortify-extension-to-ggplot2-to-handle-some-popular-packages-r-software-and-data-visualization) shows text like I'm looking to do, and I can't see any different specifications under `label.label` or anything similar.

[Here's my data in RDS format.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fe6ezwoz9885oi2/everyblock_ca.rds?dl=0) The dataframe is 77x202 so I haven't copied it here.

Here's the code that specifies the model and then plots:

```
summary(m.ca.ppc <- lm(ppc ~ medinc + hisp + black + asian, data = df.ca))
autoplot(m.ca.ppc, which = 1:6, ncol = 3, label.size = 3)
```

Which produces [image: plots produced by ggfortify]

My questions are:

1. How do I get the community names instead of the observation numbers (e.g., 39, 36 in the Residuals vs Fitted plot) to appear?
2. How do I have the label not overlap the dot so I can read it easily?

[edited to clarify after questions in the comments]

Comment: This probably belongs stackoverflow since it's all about this package.

Comment: Oh, ok. I will flag rather than create a new one.

Comment: Your first question isn't entirely clear to me. What are you referring to? I dont see any "39,36" on the plot you posted. Are you referring to the x-axis, y-axis? Also, I wasn't able to load your data into R -file seems to be corrupted.

Comment: the 39 and 36 are the observation numbers that appears as labels in the plot itself (see the Residuals vs Fitted plot, for instance).

When I download the RDS file from Dropbox, I use `df <- readRDS("everyblock_ca.rds")`, and it works. I'm not sure how else to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate text labels, point to the relevant column, and turn off the points.

```
autoplot(m.ca.ppc, data = df.ca, label.size = 3, label=TRUE, label.label="community", shape=FALSE, which=1:6, ncol=3)
```